# Unable to use Vim

Tags: vim

I downloaded the current version of Vim (which I use for Python programming) from their web site.  When I try to run it in the terminal I get the following message:

```
vim: error while loading shared libraries: liblua5.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In 18.0.4, you need to install **liblua5.2-0**.

Comment: Might be just as well with the repository vim, any special reason for installing from the vim website?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> to open `terminal`
Step 2: Run the command

```
sudo apt-get install liblua5.2-0
```

Step 3: Type `vim` in `terminal` to open `vim`